# why the zend_db does not work when I getConnection() before executing the sql script

Tags: php, zend-db

```
try
 {
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory($config->general->db->adapter, $config->general->db-        >config->toArray());

    // first 
    $sql = 'select * from department';
    $results = $dbAdapter->fetchAll($sql);

    // second 
    $db = $dbAdapter->getConnection();
    $sql = 'select * from department';
    $results = $db->fetchAll($sql);
}
catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $exc)
{
     echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
catch (Zend_Exception $exc)
{
   echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

when I use the first way, the application works well, but when I use the second way - get a connection and then run the sql scripts, it does not work, and more worse the application is blocked on the line ($db->fetchAll($sql)) and does not return any errors. 
what is the reason? did anyone encounter with this issue? btw, I am a freshman to learn PHP, I want to make some friends to learn it together. thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry for not providing the environment details, zend framework 1.11.11

Answer (score 2):

Zend_Db is in essence a wrapper of the many RDBMS PHP Modules to provide a single database abstraction interface to the Zend Framework. That means that you will end up writing your SQL requests pretty much the same way using Zend_Db, even if you are using MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL etc.

The `getConnection()` method will force the database to connect and will return the actual underlying resource/object of the database layer. I.e. if you use mysqli getConnection() will return a an object of type mysqli. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

You then assign the mysqli instance class to the `$db` variable and you try to invoke a `fetchAll()` but `fetchAll()` does not exist in the class mysqli. It probably throws out an error at this point, which if you don't have error reporting on would result to a blank page.

Check this piece of code for instance:

```
<?php
class A {}

$a = new A();
$a->doesNotExist();
```

This will throw a:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method A::doesNotExist() in
>   foobar.php on line 5

So, you can invoke the `getConnection()` to force the Database layer to connect to the RDBMS but from what I can tell there is no need for the actual resource/object being returned by the `getConnection()`. You can read more information on the getConnection() and why would someone need the resource, on the part of "Managing Lazy connections" at Zend_Db documentation - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html

You should proceed with your application as you would normally do:

```
$sql = 'select * from department';
$resource = $dbAdapter->getConnection();
$results = $dbAdapter->fetchAll($sql);
```

Btw, well asked question.

Comment: Hi @mobius thanks for your comments. the key point of my issue is that the getConnection() does not support for the $db value, correct?

Comment: @antanse Hum, I thought I did a good job explaining everything in my answer but I guess not. In short, the result of `Zend_Db::factory(...)` is not the same as the result of `Zend_Db::factory(...)->getConnection()`. Use $dbAdapter and not $db

Comment: @antanse If you feel the answer is correct please do accept it.